# I can't seem to get the values to upload into the database table

Tags: php

I can't seem to get the values to upload into the database table. It keeps giving me this error:

> Upload Error, please try again.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['musicFile']['name']))
{
    $uploaddir = "/accounts/groups/MDM2013.02/public_html/TPFinal/music/";
    $uploadfile = basename($_FILES['musicFile']['name']);
    $uploadpath = $uploaddir . $uploadfile;
    //echo substr($uploadfile, -3);
    //echo $uploaddir;
    //echo $uploadpath;
    //var_dump($uploadfile);
    if((strcasecmp(substr($uploadfile, -3), "mp3") == 0))//||(strcasecmp(substr($uploadfile, -3, 3), "wav") == 0))
    {
        if(!is_file($uploadpath))
        { 
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['musicFile']['tmp_name'],$uploadpath)) 
            {
                if((strcasecmp($type,"audio/mp3") == 0))// || (strcasecmp($type, "music/wav")== 0))
                {
                    echo "File of a valid type ($type), and was stored as $uploadfile<br/>\n";
                    $data = $_POST['musicFile']; $art = $_POST['ArtistName']; $title = $_POST['MusicTitle'];
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO Music(UserName,MusicName,MusicType, Artist, Data) VALUES ('$username','$title','$type', '$art', '$data')";
                    $result= mysql_query($sql);
                    if($result)
                    {
                        if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1)
                        {
                        echo "Music inserted into Database, with ID = ", 
                        mysql_insert_id();
                        }
                    }
                }else{echo "Failed mime-checking <br/>"; unlink($uploadpath);}

            }else{echo "Upload Error, please try again! <BR/> \n";}

        }else echo "File already exists <br/>\n";}

    else echo "Only MP3 files are acceptable ($uploadfile) <br/>\n";}

include_once ("db_close.php");
?>
```

Comment: You've not shown the code that produces that error, as far as I can tell. Does your execution path get into the first `if` block? How about the second and third? Has a file been uploaded to your upload folder? If not, could it have exceeded your max upload size?

Comment: Here is the rest:
      
if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1)
      echo "Music inserted into Database, with ID = ", 
       mysql_insert_id();
      }
         }
     else {
     echo "Failed mime-checking <br/>"; unlink($uploadpath);}
    }
    else
     echo "Upload Error, please try again! <BR/> \n"; 
   }
   else
    echo "File already exists <br/>\n";
  }
  else
   echo "Only MP3 files are acceptable ($uploadfile) <br/>\n";
   }
   
   include_once ("db_close.php");
?>

Comment: Please edit that into the question, indenting it so it is formatted as code. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like `move_uploaded_file` is failing. Temporarily, add the two paths you have supplied to that in your error message. See if they both look right. Check that you have write permissions to both, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually check what specific error you are getting. Try checking your errors [here](http://darklaunch.com/2009/05/01/php-file-upload-error-codes-upload-err-ok)